# Azure Function with Logic App Recurrence trigger

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, recurrence

What should I choose the trigger for Azure Function to use it on Logic Apps with Recurrence trigger ? On the Azure function there are an option such as HttpTrigger, EventTrigger, etc. What should I choose to trigger it using recurrence on Logic Apps ?

Comment: If you are just looking to get a function to run at a certain fixed frequency, there is no need for a logic app. Function has its own triggering mechanism.  You can follows the answer below. If you still want your Logic app trigger your function, you will need to use a http triggered function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create **Timer Triggered Azure function.** You can follow the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#create-a-timer-triggered-function) and use the CRON expression to schedule as you required

**`Schedule 0 */1 * * * *`**

Comment: If I create recurrence on logic apps, is it will be trigger by two condition (recurrence & corn express)? for example (recurrence: 5 minutes, cron express: 5 minutes, it will be totaled 10 minutes?) I'm sorry, I'm new on this function

Comment: Yes function will execute on its own based on the given configuration while logic app is a separate, I am clearly not sure why you are doing this though!